# Kohana 404 The requested URL /reviews was not found on this server

Tags: php, apache, kohana, kohana-3

Setting up a new page on-top of an existing kohana environment. I changed the httpd.config to be the following.

## Virtual hosts

Include conf/extra/httpd-vhosts.conf

```
<virtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin admin@example.com
    DocumentRoot "C:/wamp/www/site/kohana"
    ServerName localhost
</virtualHost>
<virtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin admin@example.com
    DocumentRoot "C:/wamp/www/site/kohana"
    ServerName localhost
    <directory "C:/wamp/www/site/kohana">
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride all
        Order Deny,Allow
        Deny from all
        Allow from 127.0.0.1
    </directory>
</virtualHost>
```

This allowed me to type in localhost and hit the homepage of the site. But for some reason I can only access the page which is defined in the bootstrap.php route

```
Route::set('default', '(<controller>(/<action>(/<id>)))')
    ->defaults(array(
        'controller' => 'account',
        'action'     => 'index',
    ));
```

After I go to the Account page and attempt to redirect somewhere else. I get a 404 error from apache. I assume its from apache because the error isnt thrown from kohana.

```
Not Found

The requested URL /reviews was not found on this server.
```

does anyone have suggestions as to what i should look at?

Answer (score 1):

I think in url you have skiped the file index.php

Perhaps if you type url into your web browser like this, it should work:

```
localhost/index.php/<controller>/<action>
```

not like this:

```
localhost/<controller>/<action>
```

Answer (score 0):

Check, is apache mod_rewrite enable and loaded at phpinfo();
In My case I've just enable mod_rewrite at apache.

```
 sudo a2enmod rewrite
```

and than restart

```
sudo systemctl restart apache2
```

Check .htaccess rules.

And make sure you have Controller_Welcome class, method in it.